# Can I have multiple EJB declarations for the same Home and Remote classes?

Tags: ejb, oc4j, deployment-descriptor

Can one declare multiple beans in the `ejb-jar.xml` (**in EJB 1.1**) deployment descriptor with different names but the same classes behind?

For example:

```
<session>
    <ejb-name>AccountFacade</ejb-name>
    <home>com.something.ejb.AccountFacadeHome</home>
    <remote>com.something.ejb.AccountFacadeRemote</remote>
    <ejb-class>com.something.ejb.AccountFacadeBean</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
    <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
</session>

<session>
    <ejb-name>RestrictiveAccountFacade</ejb-name>
    <home>com.something.ejb.AccountFacadeHome</home>
    <remote>com.something.ejb.AccountFacadeRemote</remote>
    <ejb-class>com.something.ejb.AccountFacadeBean</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
    <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
</session>
```

For `RestrictiveAccountFacade` I want to set a higher isolation level in the `orion-ejb-jar.xml` file, something like:

```
<entity-deployment name="AccountFacade" location="AccountFacade">
    <resource-ref-mapping location="..." name="jdbc/..."/>
</entity-deployment>

<entity-deployment name="RestrictiveAccountFacade" location="RestrictiveAccountFacade" isolation="serializable">
    <resource-ref-mapping location="..." name="jdbc/..."/>
</entity-deployment>
```

Is there a risk involved in doing this, any side effects or unspecified behavior?

Comment: In ejb-jar.xml you declared them as session beans while in orion-ejb-jar.xml as entity beans. The server didn't complain about it?

Comment: This is just an example; I didn’t actually configure it that way. It is a copy-paste error from my part. But your observation made me realize something. On the "session-deployment" tag (which should be in the above example instead of "entity-deployment") there is no such thing as an "isolation" attribute. So how (or where) do I specify the isolation level for session beans? (P.S. I will leave the example unchanged for the moment)

Comment: In this case, if there is one place for such attribute it should be data-sources.xml.

Comment: The EJB 1.1 is a blur regarding the isolation level for CMP beans, but I did some more digging and the conclusion, as I see it, is that the EJB 1.1 specification removed the guidelines for managing transaction isolation levels for beans with container-managed transaction demarcation (there is also something related to this in the book Mastering EJB, from Ed Roman, a side note in appendix D), so I can’t specify the isolation level I want. For BMP beans it might work, but this raises another question: can a safely combine BMP with CMP beans?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally OK to have it as you mentioned above. One should note that as per container is concerned `AccountFacade` and `RestrictiveAccountFacade` will be two totally unrelated session beans.

However `RestrictiveAccountFacade` has transaction serializable access to same jdbc resource as `AccountFacade` so they will interfere with each other only at transaction isolation level.

Hence `AccountFacade` may be blocked if it needs access to same record as that is participated in transaction of `RestrictiveAccountFacade`.

Similarly `RestrictiveAccountFacade` transaction will be blocked on same record as that is being used by `AccountFacade` in it's transaction.